# Nginx SSLInsecureRenegotiation equivalent

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, ssl

I'm currently migrating our ssl setup from apache to nginx, but I've hit a roadblock. In our apache config we have `SSLInsecureRenegotiation on` due to some incompatibility issues with safari. I can't find the equivalent command in nginx. Is there one?

Comment: That renegotiation vulnerability is from 2009 - are you sure you still need to support the old broken version?

Comment: All I know is we were finding that current safari on osx wasn't working, and then we added that and it was fixed, but it could be we were doing something else wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into the viability of just losing [that particular option](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslinsecurerenegotiation). As the name suggest **it's insecure!**

Nginx currently ([since 0.8.23](http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES)) does not do TLS renegotiation at all, anyway.

Also, while I realize you seem to be in a position where compatibility with broken clients seems to be more important than security (unfair argument: why are you using TLS, if you're going to poke holes in it?), I suggest checking your site with [Qualys SSL Labs's SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html).

Comment: With nginx the problem doesn't seem to occur. Could be a fault of faulty testing on our part previously, but who knows. Anyway, sometimes ignoring the problem is the best solution :)